# MYSQL: how to insert statement without specifying col names or question marks?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list of tuples of which i'm inserting into a Table.
Each tuple has 50 values. How do i insert without having to specify the column names and how many `?` there is?

`col1` is an auto increment column so my insert stmt starts in `col2` and ends in `col51`.

current code:

```
l = [(1,2,3,.....),(2,4,6,.....),(4,6,7,.....)...]

for tup in l:
    cur.execute(
"""insert into TABLENAME(col2,col3,col4.........col50,col51)) VALUES(?,?,?,.............)
""")
```

want:

```
    insert into TABLENAME(col*) VALUES(*)
```

Comment: Why not using a loop to build the query? Loop from 2 to 51 to build the 'INSERT INTO tablename' then loop through each object to send the values

Comment: What you want is not possible (probably because it's a terrible idea -- think about what would happen if someone inserted a column in the table..)

Comment: See normalisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's syntax for INSERT is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

There is no wildcard syntax like you show. The closest thing is to omit the column names:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (...);
```

But I don't recommend doing that. It works only if you are certain you're going to specify a value for every column in the table (even the auto-increment column), and your values are guaranteed to be in the same order as the columns of the table.

You should learn to use code to build the SQL query based on arrays of values in your application. Here's a Python example the way I do it. Suppose you have a dict of *column: value* pairs called `data_values`.

```
placeholders = ['%s'] * len(data_values)
sql_template = """
INSERT INTO MyTable ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders})
"""
sql = sql_template.format(
    columns=','.join(keys(data_values)),
    placeholders=','.join(placeholders)
)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute(sql, data_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

example code to put before your code:

```
cols = "("
for x in xrange(2, 52):
   cols = cols + "col" + str(x) + ","

test = test[:-1]+")"
```

Inside your loop

```
for tup in l:
    cur.execute(
"""insert into TABLENAME " + cols " VALUES {0}".format(tup)
""")
```

This is off the top of my head with no error checking